# What creates a negative charge in the material?

Tags: condensed-matter, charge, material-science, quasiparticles

What creates a negative charge in the material? Is it an electron or a holon? Holons as I understand is a math. But what then creates an electrostatic repulsion? Is it still electron?

Comment: Holons are quasiparticles that transfer charge

Answer (score 0):

For any material electrons are responsible for creating negative charge or positive charge.

Deficiency of electrons in a material creates positive charge and excess electrons in an Material create negative charge.